# Pivot table with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, pivot, pivot-table

How can I use MySQL pivot table with php to create a dynamic query for a refine search system?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'MAX(IF(ad.name = ''',
      name,
      ''', pa.text, NULL )) AS ',
      replace(name,' ', '_')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM attribute_description, product_attribute;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT p.id
                    , p.titlu
                    , p.descriere, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM produse p
                   LEFT JOIN product_attribute AS pa 
                   ON p.id = pa.product_id
                   LEFT JOIN attribute_description AS ad
                   ON pa.attribute_id = ad.attribute_id where p.vizibil=''1'' 
                group by id having tara_de_origine = "romania" and instant = "da"');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

In something like this

```
$sql = sprintf("pivot table query ......", $var, $var2);
```

My previous query was

```
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT *, p.id as pid FROM produse p 
                    INNER JOIN categorii c on p.categorie=c.id
                    LEFT JOIN product_attribute pa on p.id=pa.product_id
                    LEFT JOIN attribute_description ad on pa.attribute_id=ad.attribute_id
                    WHERE c.seo = '%s' AND p.vizibil= 1", $_GET['c']);
```

Comment: Where is [@bluefeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) when you need him?

Comment: 4 upvotes for a question that's totally unclear?

Comment: what is unclear?. I want to use the query with php like $sql = "..query.."

Comment: What does not work? What's the problem? I don't understand the snippet under "something like this". What does it have to do with the above code block? And what about your previous query. It's an entirely different query. And what's wrong with it? Actually I don't even see a real question in there.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT( 'MAX(IF(ad.name = ''', ' at line 2

Comment: Show the whole procedure. A syntax error is usually to the left of the text after "near...", since this is the first thing that's unexpected by the parser.

Comment: Hi speedy. If you have clarifications, [edit] them into the question, don't leave them buried in comments where no one will see them. For now, I'm voting to close this question as unclear, for the reasons laid out by @fancyPants.